# Error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: codeigniter, csv, upload, error-handling, fopen

I made an upload system where the user uploads a file and that file is saved and then read by php. The values are inserted into a database. The whole thing works great on the development server but not on the live server.

I have another upload system on the live site that works fine. I tried uploading it to a different folder but that didnt work either.

Just so you know the other day i had problems with the mime type. So for example i uploaded a csv file but the server read it as a text/plain document. I configured configured codeigniter to allow that for csv's so that shouldnt be the problem. Just thought it was worth mentioning.

ERROR:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(http://144.119.190.87/designUploads/testing.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Filename: controllers/headquarters.php

Line Number: 682

==================================================
PHP:

```
 public function importDesign () {
    //  setting config options
    $config['upload_path'] = './designUploads/';        
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';       
    $config['overwrite'] = 'true';      

    //  loading upload library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //  write errors to view file
    $error = '';
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $this->upload->delete($lastId);
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());      
    }

    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
    $name = $fileData['file_name'];

    Line 680 ---> if (($handle = fopen(base_url('designUploads/'. $name), "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->query('
                UPDATE rollout_systems 
                SET Mig_type = "'. $data[2] .'",
                    hardw_destination = "'. $data[3] .'",
                    new_model = "'. $data[4] .'",
                    new_system = "'. $data[5] .'",
                    Mig_Class = "'. $data[6] .'"
                WHERE sys_name = "'. $data[0] .'"
                AND EAM_User = "'. $data[1] .'"
            ');

            if ($query) {
                redirect('headquarters/migrationDetails');
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: The 401 response is being generated by the server you're connecting to, not in your own code. Presumably that server requires some kind of authentication before it will serve you that file.

Comment: You sure its nothing in the code?

Comment: What happens if you navigate to http://144.119.190.87/designUploads/ in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you two that tried to help. Found the problem while comparing both the uploads i have code. As it turns out fopen() does not support base_url(). Once i got rid of that it worked.